# React-Sidenav main content isn't styled

Tags: reactjs, navbar

i'm using this.
https://github.com/trendmicro-frontend/react-sidenav

Sidenav works well, but I do not have time to implement main content style. Do you know why main content is not included in the library? **The demo works correctly**. It will be time-consuming to write styles and logics so that the width of main content is good depending on collapse.

```
 <SideNav>
            ...
        </SideNav>
        <main>
            <Route path="/" exact component={props => <ASD/>} />
            <Route path="/asd" component={props => <ASD/>} />
            <Route path="/asd" component={props => <ASD/>} />
        </main>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs, you have to import the css like so:

```
import "@trendmicro/react-sidenav/dist/react-sidenav.css";
```

Comment: Of course. Sidenav is styled correctly. Main content doesn't work, main is "wild"..